# App runs a white screen after adding MKMapView to UIView programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, mkmapview

I'm doing this app where I use 3 different UIViews as custom cells. One of them should have a MKMapView on it's left. I should do this programmatically. I subclassed UIView and then subclassed that into children classes respectively

This is the code of the Map cell:

```
import MapKit
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class MapMimicTableViewCell: MimicTableViewCell {

var mapView = MKMapView()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
    mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)
    self.addSubview(mapView)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    titleLabel.text = "Map Cell"
}

}
```

When I comment the line

```
self.addSubview(mapView)
```

The app works normally, when I leave it the app passes the launch screen and a white screen is all I get.

What is going on?

Comment: All other Controls in Cell looks Properly?

Comment: When its commented everything works fine, when I de comment it the whole app after the launch screen is white.